# Do moderators earn a salary?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I just wonder if moderators earn any money or earn a salary for being moderators - or do they do it just to help out on the site?

Comment: Yes, we get paid with your agony. =)

Comment: I propose this as a new **feature-request**! :P

Comment: @Alenanno What, that moderators get paid? And by the number of sites you're a moderator on, I imagine? ;)

Comment: @J.Steen Oh well, I guess I'd just get one salary, not one per site. :D

Comment: @casperOne: [Garmonbozia](http://twinpeaks.wikia.com/wiki/Garmonbozia)? I knew you were a ghost, but...

Comment: its better if they got paid :)  , i wish that

Comment: But of course! [Unicorn currency cash payments](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/12-million-unicorn-bucks.jpg)! (redeemable at your local tavern [on the meta] for [sparkly handbags](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jxG7z.jpg)).

Comment: @Lix you laugh, [but...](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1292225#1292225).

Comment: @user998158 if you think they should get paid, don't just say so, please explain why.

Comment: We get to keep all the things we delete.

Comment: You keep what you kill.

Comment: because they get much work and much control

Comment: I heared that after 20 year of SE memebership your reps will be traded to bitcoins 1:1 ?

Comment: Being a moderator is such a challenging task and also time consuming. I don't know what motivates the moderators to do this.

Comment: Voluntariness is beyond money!

Answer (score 323, accepted):

## No.

[image: No. No. No. No. No. No. No. No. Hell no. No. ... No.]

Comment: is this an answer ?

Comment: Yes, it is an answer

Comment: And an accurate one at that...

Comment: ... that was easy. I wonder why that doesn't work on all of *my* answers.

Comment: @J.Steen Clearly you don't have enough animated GIFs.

Comment: One of the best answers ever!!

Comment: Someone can also take that as a ***yes*** by thinking they are paid so huge amount that they have attained a new level of happiness.

Comment: @aditya: I don't know where this gif comes from, but browsing Reddit pretty much yields an inexhaustible supply of gifs.

Comment: This mod is toooooooo cool 3:)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd why didn't you go out for mod?  nvm, you don't have to answer.  But I would have +1 that.

Comment: And I enjoy all this rep I can spread to [meta-tag:feature-request] questions that deserve attention

Comment: @Won't feel honored that you ask but I fear it will cause me to spend time that I don't have plus there are still "core" matters that I try to stay away from, something that moderator can't really do.

Comment: Hehehe Loved it!! One of the best answer

Comment: REPUTATION IS YOUR SALARY

Comment: This is called the "tracy morgan no no no gif" by reverse searching in google.

Comment: Vote up for best answer but I don't want to say **NO**.

Comment: One of the greatest answers!

Comment: Why pay money for something when individuals are able and willing to do it for free.

Answer (score 78):

No they don't.  It's an all volunteer effort.

Note that there are also Stack Exchange employees that do moderation work.

Comment: Employees only moderate in extremis.

Comment: its better if they got paid :)

Answer (score 63):

The benefits of being a moderator:

1. A huge say in the direction of a site.
2. Access to the site views.
3. The ability to choose an organization of a list of a few to receive $100 once a year from Stack Exchange.
4. More direct access to the Stack Exchange employees.
5. That warm fuzzy feeling of making a difference.
6. Access to the Teacher's Lounge, a chat room for moderators.
7. Once in a blue moon, SE will hire one of the community moderators as "Community Managers".
8. The ability to edit chat messages after 2 minutes.
9. Occasionally you get a piece of clothing. I received a hat, some receive a t-shirt. But these are pretty random.

As has been noted, SE staff also has access, who do get paid. But there are some 500+ (Maybe even more?) moderators, including myself, who don't receive a dime for their services.

Comment: I moderated Stack Exchange and all I got was… no, scratch that, not even a lousy T-shirt. (You do get a T-shirt for *running* in a mod election though.)

Comment: @Gilles: Running and not winning, if I remember right. Hmmm...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto , Are you thinking...What I'm thinking?

Comment: @Gilles: Really? _goes off to nominate self everywhere_

Comment: You get stuff for winning an election too. Not sure what it used to be, but now it's a t-shirt. (And @Manishearth: ಠ_ಠ).

Comment: @AnnaLear: Is that just for SO? I recall winning an election but I don't recall getting a tshirt for it, ಠ_ಠ right back at you :P

Comment: @Manishearth That all hinges on me going through my backlog of election participants that need to be contacted. :) I'm gonna be catching up on all of that in the next week or two.

Comment: The elected mods get business cards too, don't they?

Comment: I never have gotten any. Man, I'm feeling cheated out of all of the things I should be getting as a mod of 2 sites that I'm not...

Comment: @AnnaLear: Ah, I see. ಠ◡ಠ

Comment: @иɪvэЖєvɪɴ There are a few sites where those cards haven't been designed yet, but otherwise, yeah.

Comment: @иɪvэЖєvɪɴ /cc Pearson: You need a meta post tagged [business cards] to get cards. For that, you need to bug Jin. Jin said something about getting to them in December but he may have forgotten :s (See http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=card&Room=4&User=19&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest)

Comment: The benefits to Stackoverflow: one of the most difficult problems in running an online business solved for free. That "warm fuzzy feeling" is the feeling of being cheated into doing something for free that a profitable business should be paying for... and lessening the unemployment rate at the same time.

Comment: I don't understand 3rd point.

Comment: @Murtaza: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/stack-exchange-gives-back-2013-2/

Comment: Alas, there's no more swag for running in or winning an election.

Answer (score 42):

Moderating SE is a volunteer effort. We don't get paid for it, and we are free to step down whenever we want to. It's not always a fun job, but it has its high points and you get a sense of satisfaction as you see a site progress, knowing that you were (and still are) an integral part of it.

Most of us also have a natural tendency to participate in every meta discussion that ever comes up (the fact that we get inbox pings for every new meta question helps). While our words on meta don't hold much more intrinsic weight (except in extreme cases where the community is very divisive over an issue), the community generally respects and follows our opinion on a matter, so we end up "leading" the community at time. Again, one gets a sense of satisfaction for this.

SE also [donates money to charities chosen by us every year](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/stack-exchange-gives-back-2012/).

Comment: -1 for a serious answer. We don't care for those.

Comment: +1 on the comment just to confuse readers.

Comment: -1 on the comment indicating a +1 on the previous comment; +1 on the previous comment; -0 on the answer; +1 on the question; +1 lumps on my head.

Comment: +0 for Andrews's comment for mentioning +1 too many times.

Comment: @AndrewBarber +1 for figuring out how to -1 on a comment. Share? ;)

Comment: @wendikidd Ancient evil-unicorn secret!

Comment: + and - for confusing us in Math. **What numbers should I use?**

Answer (score 10):

From the [Moderator Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement)

> I acknowledge and agree that **I am an independent volunteer moderator** for one or more sites operated by Stack Exchange, Inc. and **I am not an employee, agent or representative** of Stack Exchange, Inc., and I have no authority to bind Stack Exchange, Inc. in any manner and I am solely responsible for my statements and actions. I attest that my statements and posts do not represent the views, opinions or actions of Stack Exchange, Inc.

Now a [volunteer](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/volunteer) is "A person who works for an organization without being paid".

So, **NO**, *but with sources*!