# Collapsible/Pauseable GIFs in chat

Tags: discussion, chat, images

An extension of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183253/disable-gif-auto-play-in-chat), gifs are fun, but in chat, they can get annoying. Especially when the conversation dies and all you can see is the same image looping constantly, it has sometimes led to simply deleting the image later, or multi-posting in an attempt to simply push it out of view.

In the linked question, the suggestion to add a "pause/play" function the gif was one thought, but perhaps a simpler one might be that after a period of time, it simply reverts back to the original url link, maybe after a period of time (potentially the easiest option), or by clicking it.