# Your gifs make me sick: Please disable auto-play

Tags: bug, design, images, accessibility

On Stack Exchange, gifs play automatically. See the [lower part of this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310920/323179) for an example without too much motion/flashing.

To many people, autoplay is merely an annoyance. However, to photosensitive people, certain gifs cause nausea, physical pain, or even something as severe as a seizure. According to the [Epilepsy Foundation](https://www.epilepsy.com/what-is-epilepsy/seizure-triggers/photosensitivity):

> Many people are not aware they are sensitive to flickering lights or to certain kinds of patterns until they have a seizure. They may never go on to develop epilepsy with spontaneous seizures. They could only have seizures triggered by certain photic (light) conditions.
>
> Many other individuals who are disturbed by light exposure do not develop seizures at all, but have other symptoms, such as headache, nausea, dizziness, and more.

WCAG also has requirements that animations not be the type that are likely to cause these negative effects.

While most users are reasonable about what gifs they post, there are some who aren't (perhaps due to ignorance). We shouldn't let anyone suffer because of that. There are two options I can think of:

- Don't autoplay any gifs. Click on the gif to play/pause.
- The above but only for a user who [`prefers-reduced-motion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion).

Personally, I would prefer option #1 above, consistent with how embedded YouTube videos work. It's not like this is a gif sharing site where people may want to play hundreds of gifs in an hour.

A similar thing has [already been requested for chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183253/323179) with some good screenshots showing this behavior on another website. See also the [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Seizure_disorders) on the subject.

Comment: Do you have a proposal for how to trick the browser into rendering only the initial frame of a GIF? I'm not aware of any way for HTML, CSS, or JS to selectively control the animation properties of a GIF, short of parsing, extracting a single frame, recompressing, and encoding the new data to base64. I know firefox has a hidden option to disable animations, but it's not easily toggleable (at least not without reloading the page).

Comment: @vandench In the MSN guide see "Resources for detecting and controlling animated GIFs". Other sites do it so I can't imagine it being too hard.

Comment: The MDN article seems to link to two libraries that are capable of "controlling" the animation of a GIF. One seems to require the server be able to supply the same image as a PNG. The other (linked through an SO post) seems to parse the GIF, extract single frame, and render it to a canvas. The former would require whatever new image provider to support the conversion, the latter sounds unpleasant for frontend performance and battery life.

Comment: @Chenmunka According to FR I linked about chat, Opera disables animated gifs by default. But they still auto play in most other browsers, including Chrome.

Comment: @Vickel This will turn attaching short animations to posts from “difficult” to “entirely impossible”. I wish I could have uploaded a real video file to <https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18157/15334>, but failing that, an animated GIF (or APNG) is the closest I could do.

Comment: @Chenmunka nope. It's not default in any browser, see [this](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-stop-gifs-from-auto-playing-in-your-browser).

Comment: Use Firefox and then you can disable image animation altogether http://kb.mozillazine.org/Animated_images

Comment: One complication here is that it's become common for websites to describe actual videos - especially in formats like webm - falsely as "gifs".

Answer (score 18):

This is, technically, very difficult. Frankly, it's not the responsibility of a website to do this: would you expect [a video file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF) to embed [a computer program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_menu#Programming_interface) that asks you whether you want to play sound? But browser developers have been shirking their responsibilities. In many cases, they've exposed JavaScript APIs allowing web developers to implement it (on an ad-hoc, per-site basis), but this is not possible for everything.

There is no way to detect whether an image in an `<img>` tag is animated, client-side. (Short of downloading a second copy, hopefully served by the browser's cache, hoping CORS lets it through, and then parsing the file format in JavaScript…) There is no *good* way to handle this server-side, as long as hotlinking remains supported, and there are licensing issues preventing an automatic migration away from hotlinked images.

A few browsers can be reconfigured to disable animated gifs:

- Firefox and derivatives: In `about:config`, set `image.animation_mode` to `none`. (Per the [MozillaZine Knowledge Base article](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Animated_images).)
- Chromium and derivatives: Doesn't exist, though there are browser extensions available. (I can't vouch for any: I avoid Google.)
- Internet Explorer: On a per-page basis, you can press the Esc key to stop gifs from playing. (This *used* to work in Firefox, too.) Alternatively, Internet Options → Advanced → Multimedia → Play animations in webpages* (requires restarting Internet Explorer) to disable it globally.

The real solution is to *get a better browser*. Stack Exchange [doesn't *support*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/308065) any of the actually half-decent browsers (creating a sort of catch-22: don't support because unused / don't use because unsupported), but I'm hoping that will change… eventually.

---

> While most users are reasonable about what gifs they post, there are some who aren't (perhaps due to ignorance). We shouldn't let anyone suffer because of that.

As with other material that harms the reader, we should *remove such images* or – where that's not sensible – put them behind spoiler markup. There's been increased awareness of alt text among editors as of late: perhaps that can extend to this, too.

Comment: canvas workaround? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5818003/11107541. as for detecting animation, you can at least check the content type somewhat easily: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43467909/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/72796785/11107541

Comment: @starball The canvas workaround requires JavaScript: what's the fallback? It's also not an optimised code path. Detecting content type doesn't tell you whether it's _animated_: `image/gif`, `image/png`, `image/jpeg` and `image/webp` can all be animated or static. (Btw, don't use WebP.)

Comment: png can be animated? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG#:~:text=Although%20GIF%20allows%20for%20animation%2C%20it%20was%20decided%20that%20PNG%20should%20be%20a%20single%2Dimage%20format.

Comment: @starball [Yup.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) Strictly speaking, it's not PNG, but it uses the same MIME type; as, I believe, does MJPEG. While I'm here: content type detection is restricted by CORS, so won't work for most hotlinked images (and if we're not supporting those, a server-side approach is best).