# What does "company's moderators" mean?

Tags: support, moderation, company

In the recent [Wired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_(magazine)) article, ["Stack Overflow Will Charge AI Giants for Training Data"](https://www.wired.com/story/stack-overflow-will-charge-ai-giants-for-training-data/), there is the following statement:

> Chandrasekar says a spike in inaccurate answers following the release of ChatGPT had created a challenge for the company’s several hundred or so moderators.

How close is that to what Prashanth Chandrasekar actually said (is it highly paraphrased)?

And what does "moderator" mean here? Is it referring to the diamond moderators across the network? Or is it referring to the community?

If it's referring to the diamond moderators, this statement is missing the fact that a ***lot*** of the "moderation" activities are done by members of the community with said moderation privileges without being diamond moderators. The moderators are not the only ones with hands on the effort to weed out AI content. See also *[A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)*.

If it's referring to community contributors with various levels of moderation privileges, the number is totally off.

In any case, why was it phrased "company's [...] moderators" and not "community's [...] moderators"?

What would it mean for a diamond moderator or a non-diamond-"moderator" (one who performs moderation actions) like me to be "the company's"? Neither groups get paid (related: [Is Stack Exchange in violation of New York labor law, in using volunteer moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337117/997587)), and I for one don't make my non-money-compensated contributions for the benefit of a corporation, but for other people, for free. I perform my moderation activities operating under guidance that (to my knowledge) is built by/with the community. I'm bound by the Terms of Service and the Code of Conduct, but so is every other Stack Exchange user. Moderators (except when elected pro-tempore) are elected by their community, and perform their duties in service of their community. That in my mind makes me "the community's contributor" and not the company's, and diamond moderators "the community's moderators" and not the company's.

While I can understand something thinking so, I don't think I'm looking too deep into this. It really was confusing for me to read that sentence. I personally think the choice of words is important in cases like this where the "outside world" is reading- that they'll get a proper understanding of what we are. I think even small word choices like this can matter. To me, "company's moderators" causes me to assume that the moderators are hired by the company and work with the company's best interests at the top of their mind at all times, which I don't think is the case.

Comment: Behind the scenes - there's a fairly obvious to extreme increase in flags, which is very much something that affects the diamond mods more

Comment: 1) no, the CEO was not referring ordinary users, even high rep, only actual mods (who handle ChatGPT flags). 2) Yeah, you dig bit too deep in this, IMO. :)

Comment: A huge chunk of the active community on Stack Exchange doesn't know the difference between staff, moderators, curators, and the privileges granted by reputation. You think a journalist, who's not aware of the disconnect between the CEO's speeches and the action on the 'ground' is going to have a better idea? -1 for way overthinking to the point it's nonsense.

Comment: @Nij as I've stated, it's not clear to me whether Prashanth said this, or the author of the article chose those words in paraphrase/summarization. If it was Prashanth, I personally think the choice of words is important in cases like this where the "outside world" is reading- that they'll get a proper understanding of what we are. I think even small word choices like this can matter. So we disagree. Fine.

Comment: Also, stack exchange network moderators are absolutely not "the company's". We don't work for SE, we aren't chosen by SE (with exceptions, pro tem mods are chosen) and we are neither beholden to nor in any way representatives of SE. They have no business calling us "their" moderators, we are the network's moderators, the community's moderators but we do not, in any way belong to the company.

Comment: He probably said "our moderators" or something along those lines, not implying "ownership" but just kinship. And Wired wrote what they interpreted (and they might have even added numbers that he didn't specify). But I'm staff and even I can only vaguely speculate about the actual words Prashanth used. Prashanth could only possibly speak to what he said, you may have better luck asking Wired what they actually _meant_.

Comment: @Philippe I don't think your answer on the other question addresses this concern about the wording here. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Moving to vote to reopen this question too. I am assuming good intentions (for discoverability purposes), but since this is the *second* question with such a dubious closure:  Philippe, please, do not forget that the community closes questions as duplicates when there is an *answer on the duplicate target* that address the core problem of the question.

Answer (score 8):

I do think it means the 'formal' moderation teams on the individual sites, as opposed to broader community metamoderation.

In the *context* of folks abusing [LLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_language_model) tools—most sites have had folks posting things, and the workload could range from 1-2 flags a month on a quiet site (which often has almost no flags to deal with) to several hundred flags a month.

In a sense, it’s 'workload' that isn't entirely necessary if not for folks trying their luck with these tools—and since they are 'unusual' situations, not covered by existing tools, it’s almost always handled with a custom flag by a diamond moderator eventually.

The number is accurate in terms of diamond moderators network wide. It doesn't refer to folks with moderation related privileges, active or otherwise across the network.

Comment: Thanks! I do want to get a staff answer about "_In any case, why was it phrased "company's \[...\] moderators" and not "community's \[...\] moderators"?_" though.

Comment: First impression when seeing "company moderator" without context is a CM, kind of moderator, but that works for the company. But in the context of the blog post it's clear he means the hundreds of moderators all over SE. Community moderators, are mods on single site, afaik, as each site is referred to sometimes as "community", but this can change with context as well. /cc @starball (instead of writing under the question as well. ;))

Comment: To be fair - if SE *could* afford a few hundred Community Managers, and not treat them like many US companies treat their *content* moderators, I'd have no complaints :D