# Why hasn't there been an official community announcement or blogpost about charging for usage of subscriber content in the training of LLMs?

Tags: support, announcements, company, business-model

Note for any confused: "Subscriber Content" is used here in the sense of the phrase defined in the [Terms of Service](/legal/terms-of-service).

I just saw two posts ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388551/997587), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424299/11107541)) about this [Wired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_(magazine)) article: [Stack Overflow Will Charge AI Giants for Training Data](https://www.wired.com/story/stack-overflow-will-charge-ai-giants-for-training-data/).

Unless I missed something (in which case I apologize!), there hasn't been an MSE post or blogpost about this. ([Here's a web archive snapshot of the blog I just took](https://web.archive.org/web/20230421010919/https://stackoverflow.blog/).) If that's the case...

I'd feel like I had an important conversation happen behind my back.

Or like a kid whose parents made a decision with significant implications toward their life and then told them after the fact. Actually, we wouldn't have even gotten to the being-told-after-the-fact part yet.

Not that telling us first would have made any difference to the fact of its eventual happening, but something about transparency itself is important to me.

**Where's the featured MSE post / blogpost?**

<strike>(Okay, so you've (Phillipe) closed my post as a duplicate of [Is SE [going to be] selling our content for AI model training? And what exactly does "reinvest back into our communities" mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388551/997587), but that post isn't featured. So what gives? And no, the answer there doesn't answer my question of ***why*** either)</strike> (post re-opened by community)

And **what conversation is being cited in the Wired article?** The article quotes Prashanth Chandrasekar several times, but (unless I'm missing something) it doesn't mention where or when this conversation happened. I'm feeling quite lost. In this age where it's so easy to generate convincing falsehood, it's not even out of my mind that those quotes are referencing words that were never truly uttered.

---

Update: pretty much [the same thing happened again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/398447/997587)- this time with details about what the Gemini partnership will mean.

Comment: This makes a 4th, as you also made a [3rd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388554/what-does-companys-moderators-mean). Considering that this is after all the community's content, now that you mention it, a featured post on MSE in advance, should be mandatory.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if all this came up in a meeting of some sort, and they're just beginning to work out an approach

Comment: @JourneymanGeek huh. how would the author of that wired article know about that though? 

Comment: That's a mild annoyance. Was this an interview? A news release?  There's no mention of the primary source. That said, there's a few pieces of news that seems to be a response to LLM models at the same time, and it seems reasonable to assume they are linked

Comment: @JourneymanGeek this feels like 2019 once again...

Comment: Well, yes and no. I don't really feel like there's obvious malice, only a certain level of lack of communication between the different parts of the company, which is business as usual.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. nah, not at all IMO. People are just sensitive to AI (myself included) so giving this more weight. Also, there's no victim... ;)

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Are we **all** victims as it is **our** contributions under discussion here?

Comment: Related: [Can SE just resell our data, relicense it and remove the attribution requirement?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388571/can-se-just-resell-our-data-relicense-it-and-remove-the-attribution-requirement)

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't see it this way. Maybe I just care less for attribution in general, but also one can consider the money given to SE as money given to the users, to compensate for this lack of attribution, and I find it fair.

Comment: @Philippe notice that I asked "_Where's the featured MSE post / blogpost?_" you closed this post pointing to [an MSE answer post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388551/997587), which cannot be featured. Unless you plan to feature the question post it's posted under?

Comment: Moving to vote to reopen too: the official answer on the duplicate target doesn't explain anything about why we ended up finding out about this from a Wired article as opposed to SE's official channels.