# Do Moderators of community make money or get paid?

Tags: feature-request, moderators

Do Moderators of the community make any money or get paid from SE.

Just wanted to know what is the motivation factors that drive them to work as a moderator ?

Comment: It is sheer love what drives them. And that goes much under appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do moderators earn a salary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169205/do-moderators-earn-a-salary)

Comment: I think the will of building a community where people freely share knowledge is crucial. At least that's what drives me.

Comment: Wouldn't being paid be lumped in the "making money" category?